# Realm backed by several files?

Tags: realm, realm-migration

Is it possible to manage data stored amongst several files?

Let's say I have several files `data1.realm`, `data2.realm`, `data3.realm`, etc. containing objects with the same model. Is it possible to get a unique `RLMRealm` instance that will access the datas of all these files?

If not, what is the best way to handle this situation? Migration?

Comment: One Realm instance belongs to one Configuration, and one configuration belongs to one file.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to manage data stored amongst separate Realms, but it wouldn't be automatic. You would need to manage access to this data in your own app's logic.

`RLMRealm` instances themselves represent a single file on disk and cannot be dynamically created to reference combinations of other Realms. Once an `RLMObject` has been added to a parent `RLMRealm`, it cannot be moved/backed to another `RLMRealm` representing a different file.

It most likely depends on your specific use-cases, but the simplest solution would be to simply query for your objects in separate `RLMRealm` instances for each file, and placing the resulting `RLMResults` objects from each one in an `NSArray`.

While data can't be directly shared between Realms, you could use globally unique primary keys (For example `NSUUID`) to indicate relationships between objects in different Realms.

If you need, it's also possible to create Realmless copies of `RLMObject`s if you do end up wanting to move objects between Realms:

```
Dog *savedDog = [[Dog allObjects] firstObject];
Dog *copiedDog = [[Dog alloc] initWithValue:savedDog];
```